# Java parsing HTML with dynamic pages

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I've come to a halt.

For school project we have to parse shitton of links formatted: http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Desperado%20(1995). If you go to this link, you'll see that page gets built dynamically.

How could I use jsoup.org or something similar to get HTML to my procedures? I'm trying to parse some names out of these pages.

I tried this:

```
        Document doc;

    doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    System.out.println("text : " + doc.title());
```

but it returns 403.

Help:(

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: links formated: http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Desperado%20(1995) -> strings

Comment: Also note that http://www.imdb.com/robots.txt disallows /M/* for * so crawling this is in violation of internet norms.

Comment: ohh:S That changes things alot.. TNX

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure to use [**connect(String url)**](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect%28java.lang.String%29) method initialize all default parameter before getting result, If not you may first do,

**Try this way,**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112851/")
.data("query", "Java")
.userAgent("Mozilla")
.cookie("auth", "token")
.timeout(3000)
.get();
String title = doc.title();
System.out.println("text : " + title);
```

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, I cannot input your kind of parameter. I only have URLs like this: http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?In+the+Company+of+Men+(1997) which is kind of a search page that redirects user to your kind of link.. So in code I firstly have to get redirected from http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?In+the+Company+of+Men+(1997) to http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119361/..